# Xml Node Search

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml schema. This schema is not certain of nodes.I'm searching for nodes. I want something like, for example, the search result is at the bottom of node. I want to see the ancestors top.

```
var query = from c in XMLDoc.Descendants("Nodes")
                        where c.Attribute("ExamleField") != null && (string)c.Attribute("ExamleField").Value == "321"
                        select c;
```

Comment: Is it even a valid syntax ? what kind of language is that ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `XDocument` and [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

In that case, you can find the parent element of any node with [`XObject.Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  To iterate through all parents of a node, use [`XNode.Ancestors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.ancestors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If the node is an element, you can use [`XElement.AncestorsAndSelf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.ancestorsandself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thus if you want to select all `"GroupingNode"` elements containing the queried elements, you could do something like:

```
        var query = from c in XMLDoc.Descendants("Nodes")
                    where c.Attribute("ExamleField") != null && (string)c.Attribute("ExamleField").Value == "321"
                    let a = c.Ancestors("GroupingNode").FirstOrDefault()
                    where a != null
                    select a;
```